# PHP oci_fetch_array on JOIN query skipping the while loop

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Having some trouble looping over results from my SQL query using PHP.

The script works fine when I query only one table, but completely skips my while loop when using a join.

e.g.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM WFH_USER_DETAILS WHERE USERNAME='$username'";

$result = oci_parse($con, $query);

if(oci_execute($result)) {  

    while($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

                    echo 'Working';

    }
```

The above works fine, but when I try;

```
$query = "SELECT ud.*, t.TOTAL_STEPS FROM WFH_USER_DETAILS ud, WFH_TOTALS t WHERE ud.USERNAME=t.USERNAME AND ud.USERNAME='$username'";

$result = oci_parse($con, $query);

if(oci_execute($result)) {  

    while($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

                echo 'Working';

    }
```

The oci_execute works fine on both occasions but in the latter it won't even reach my echo... Seemingly just skipping the while loop. I've looked through the docs to see if there is different syntax when using joins but I can't seem to find anything.

Any help would be great.
Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe `$row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)` return false? Have you run your query against your database directly? Make sure that it returns something.

Comment: The query works fine if I run it from terminal and through my database software... Just not in the script :(

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ps -ef and/or ls -ltr
```

to see what user has the apache/php process running.

Then do:

```
chown (username):(group) thatfile.php
```

For example, if PHP is using a user and group called 'www-data', I would do this:

```
chown www-data:www-data myquery.php
```

Then:

```
chmod 755 myquery.php
```